# Unable to Click on a <div> button using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I want to click a button which is actually a `<div>` tag. I am unable to click on it.

HTML snippet

```
<div id="search_product" class="ng-scope" ng-init="init({ searchPath: { simple: '/marketing/campaigns/search_product', advanced: '/marketing/campaigns/search' }, searchLimit: 5000 })" rms-modal="">
```

Here is Selenium Webdriver code for the click operation:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ng-scope")).click();
```

Comment: Did you wait for your JavaScript stuff to be initialized before trying to click that thing? Or did you actually type `class="ng-scope"` into your HTML?

Comment: I waited for the JavaScript stuff to be initialized before trying to click.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: No error message is displayed. Click operation is not performed. And the control goes to the next line of code.

Comment: I don't exactly see what's supposed to react to a click in any of the code you've posted though. Hard to say why it doesn't work when you haven't posted the relevant code.

Comment: A set of search results would be displayed on clicking. We also need to select the search results. As it is not clicking no search result is displayed. post click code  `List <WebElement> a = new ArrayList <WebElement>();
      
       a=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='b-border-right b-head-sub']/input"));
       for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
       {
        a.get(i).click();
      }`

Comment: Did you wait for a particular time i mean did you use thread.sleep()/ implicit wait

Comment: Yes, used Thread.sleep

Comment: What does that `div` render? So, what  do you see to click on?

Comment: That `div` is apparently not the element you need to click. Try another one in the area? Post some more of the surrounding HTML, try a few more things and post what you have tried.

Comment: `<div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}">
<div class="modal-content" modal-transclude="">
<div id="search_product" class="ng-scope" ng-init="init({ searchPath: { simple: '/marketing/campaigns/search_product', advanced: '/marketing/campaigns/search' }, searchLimit: 5000 })" rms-modal="">
<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `driver.findElement(By.id("search_product")).click();`

the problem seems to be with the locator you have selected. There can be multiple div elements with the same class name. Selenium finds the first element which matches the locator and fires the action upon it.